# QuantLib Gsr model

Tags: stochastic-processes, python, quantlib, short-rate

Almost spent the whole day. Could anyone give a link to the Gsr model specification that is implemented in QuantLib? Or give an explanation? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the model is described in Andersen, Piterbarg: Interest Rate Modeling. The formulas that are acutally implemented are derived here

https://ssrn.com/abstract=2246013

Best
Peter